# How was the pronunciation of Data decided?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data, pronunciation

There are at least two ways to pronounce the word "data".  How was the pronunciation of Data's name in *TNG* decided?

Comment: Just the one right way, though.

Comment: [One is his name, the other is not](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqwx2XFb1fQ)

Comment: It may seem trivial, but commas and periods ALWAYS go inside quotation marks. This is a common error, but it should say "data." Please keep it as is (if you want it to look good).

Comment: @T-1000'sSon : No.  My British education disagrees with that. Please consult the *Oxford Grammar, Spelling, Grammar, and Punctuation Dictionary*.  I just did.  I hope there are no hard feelings, but I have to roll back your edit (again).

Comment: @T-1000'sSon : See the accepted answer at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23/. A notable point elsewhere on that page: *If you're an American, periods or commas almost always go inside the quotation marks. If you're British, periods and commas only go inside if they're part of the actual quote.* Also: *Punctuation inside quotes is a rule that was invented by American publishers and is not necessarily followed elsewhere.*

Comment: Okay, fine, but considering this is an American website, you should adhere to American rules of punctuation. Frankly, it looks crappy to leave the period outside of the quotation marks, but have it your way!

Comment: @T-1000'sSon: The site may be hosted by an America-based company, but it's definitely international. Please don't try to enforce some global spelling rules, every user is free to use his preferred ones (as long as they are consistent within the same post).

Comment: To be overly and annoyingly correct, Data should be called Datum, because after all, he's just one person.

Comment: @Bergi My comment was somewhat tongue-in-cheek. I realize that British punctuation is different than American punctuation.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon build a firewall around this site and make praxis pay for it!

Comment: Seriously though, I learned punctuation should go outside quotation marks. I'm American.

Comment: It depends. Colons and semi-colons do go outside of quotation marks. But anyway.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon as Praxis says you're wrong. And it wouldn't be called a 'period' either, would it? Incidentally you'll find that in American [English] quotations are (always?) like "What did you say?" (double quote) where in English proper it's more common to be 'What did you say?'. And in technical documents there is even more reason for punctuation to be outside the quotes (but I'll not get into that one).

Edit: Ah, you might have already addressed that. Still, I listed some examples.

Comment: That's an old conversation. In American English, periods and commas go inside quotation marks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Patrick Stewart crystallized the pronunciation during the first script reading

I'm at the **Star Trek 50th Anniversary Celebration** in Las Vegas right now.  **Brent Spiner** just revealed the answer to this on stage.

He mentioned that he himself would have pronounced it "Daa-ta", but Patrick Stewart read it as **"Mr. Day-ta"** in the first script reading (in front of Gene Roddenberry) and it stuck.

Spiner added that he believes Patrick Stewart's pronunciation of the word has affected its overall pronunciation in North America.

Comment: It's fitting that Patrick Stewart played a role in this, as he was the one initially chosen to play Data (until Roddenberry was finally convinced that a bald captain was okay).